# Python - multi-line raw_input with .format or %s

Tags: python, raw-input, string.format

I want to do something functionally equivalent to this:

```
my_dict = {'option1': 'VALUE1', 'option2': 'VALUE2'}
def my_func():
    menu_option = raw_input(
        "Which option would you like to configure [0]?\n"
        "[0] NO CHANGES\n"
        "[1] Option1: \t{0}\n".format(my_dict.get('option1'))
        "[2] Option2: \t{0}\n".format(my_dict.get('option2'))
    ) or "0"
```

OR

```
my_dict = {'option1': 'VALUE1', 'option2': 'VALUE2'}
def my_func():
    menu_option = raw_input(
        "Which option would you like to configure [0]?\n"
        "[0] NO CHANGES\n"
        "[1] Option1: \t %s \n" % my_dict.get('option1')
        "[2] Option2: \t %s \n" % my_dict.get('option2')
    ) or "0"
```

Where the result of running my_func() looks like this:

```
Which option would you like to configure [0]?
[0] NO CHANGES
[1] Option1:     VALUE1
[2] Option2:     VALUE2
```

I'm getting an invalid syntax error.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiline string while combining it with `format` calls; use either a multiline string with single format

```
menu_option = raw_input("""
    Which option would you like to configure [0]?
    [0] NO CHANGES
    [1] Option1: \t{0}
    [2] Option2: \t{1}
    """.format(my_dict.get('option1'), my_dict.get('option2'))
) or "0"
```

or add concatenation operators

```
menu_option = raw_input(
    "Which option would you like to configure [0]?\n" + \
    "[0] NO CHANGES\n" + \
    "[1] Option1: \t{0}\n".format(my_dict.get('option1') + \
    "[2] Option2: \t{0}\n".format(my_dict.get('option2')
) or "0"
```

Comment: Ugh that second option is ugly.

Comment: @enderland I would usually go for the first for nice graphics printing, and for the second for readibility and maintenance when the formatted arguments are more verbose

Comment: Precisely.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Multiline comments are written with `"""`:

```
my_dict = {'option1': 'VALUE1', 'option2': 'VALUE2'}
def my_func():
    menu_option = raw_input(
        """Which option would you like to configure [0]?
        [0] NO CHANGES
        [1] Option1: \t{0}
        [2] Option2: \t{1}\n""".format(my_dict.get('option1'), my_dict.get('option2'))
    ) or "0"
```